# Filestream Bytes not written properly

Tags: delphi, filestream, unicode-string, delphi-10.1-berlin

Why do I get the wrong output using the following code in RAD Studio 10.1?

```
var
  sPalette : string;
  mystream: TfileStream;
begin
  mystream := TfileStream.Create('C:\Data\test.bmp', fmCreate);
  sPalette := #1#2#3#4#5#6;
  mystream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(sPalette)^, Length(sPalette));
  mystream.Free;
end;
```

Got Output : `01 00 02 00 03 00`

Expected output : `01 02 03 04 05 06`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Delphi 2009+, `string` is a 16-bit, UTF-16 encoded `UnicodeString`.  You are not taking into account that `SizeOf(Char)` is 2 bytes, not 1 byte as you are expecting.  `Length(string)` is expressed in number of characters, not in number of bytes.  Your string is 6 characters in length, but is 12 bytes in size.  You are writing only the 1st 6 bytes of the `string` to your file.  And since your `string` contains ASCII characters below `#128`, every other byte will be `$00`.

Use an 8-bit `AnsiString` instead, eg:

```pascal
var
  sPalette : AnsiString;
  mystream: TFileStream;
begin
  mystream := TFileStream.Create('C:\Data\test.bmp', fmCreate);
  try
    sPalette := #1#2#3#4#5#6;
    mystream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(sPalette)^, Length(sPalette));
  finally
    mystream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or, use `TEncoding` to convert the Unicode string to an 8-bit byte encoding:

```pascal
var
  sPalette : string;
  bytes: TBytes;
  mystream: TFileStream;
begin
  mystream := TFileStream.Create('C:\Data\test.bmp', fmCreate);
  try
    sPalette := #1#2#3#4#5#6;
    bytes := TEncoding.Default.GetBytes(sPalette);
    mystream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(bytes)^, Length(bytes));
  finally
    mystream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
var
  sPalette : string;
  mystream: TStreamWriter;
begin
  mystream := TStreamWriter.Create('C:\Data\test.bmp', False, TEncoding.Default);
  try
    sPalette := #1#2#3#4#5#6;
    mystream.Write(sPalette);
  finally
    mystream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Though, you really should not be using a `string` for binary data in the first place. Use a byte array instead, eg:

```pascal
var
  bytes: TBytes;
  mystream: TFileStream;
begin
  mystream := TFileStream.Create('C:\Data\test.bmp', fmCreate);
  try
    SetLength(bytes, 6);
    bytes[0] := $1;
    ...
    bytes[5] := $6;
    mystream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(bytes)^, Length(bytes));
  finally
    mystream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or better, just use a `TBitmap` object, since you are writing to a `.bmp` file, eg:

```pascal
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    ...
    bmp.SaveToFile('C:\Data\test.bmp');
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for Information,but If i use Ansistring then It  will work for #128 ?

Comment: @Ankush if you are careful, but it's risky.